# Unable to creating admin user, ejabberd through docker

Tags: docker, ejabberd

By following the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/ejabberd/ecs/), when trying to run the command

```
PS C:\Users\user_name> docker exec -it ejabberd bin/ejabberdapi register --endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:5280/ --jid=admin@localhost --password=passw0rd
```

to create an admin user, it shows the following error

```
ejabberdapi: error: user registration error for admin@localhost: Error 99: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Comment: Crossposted in https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work correctly using this method?

```
docker exec -it ejabberd bin/ejabberdctl register admin localhost passw0rd
```